# $X\sim\operatorname{Pois}(2)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Pois}(5)$ are independent. How to obtain the mean and variance of $X-Y$?

Tags: poisson-distribution

If both random variables X and Y are Poisson then their mean is equal to their variance respectively. I thought of subtracting both means but I realise, how was I going to get the variance. Poisson distribution=(μ^x.e^-μ)÷(x!). Where μ= mean,
X can assume any number.

Comment: For independent random variables $X$, $Y$ and scalars $a,b\in\Bbb R$: $\mathsf{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\mathsf{Var}X+b^2\mathsf{Var}Y$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how exactly can I solve for the mean .

Comment: Expectation is Linear (for any random variables).  $\mathsf E(aX+bY)=a\,\mathsf E\,X+b\,\mathsf E\,Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $X,Y$ are Poisson,

$$E(X)=Var(X)=2\\
E(Y)=Var(Y)=5$$

Thus

$$E(X-Y)=2-5=-3\\
Var(X-Y)=2+5=7$$

Comment: Thanks for your support, but please why is the variance 7 instead of 3. Then the mean will be equal to the variance making the distribution Poisson, can you please explain further.

Comment: @Ernest $Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+(-1)^2Var(Y)=2+5=7$. The coefficient of Y is squared, so it becomes +1 by a squaring operation.